# How to find next row's value by comparing it to the previous value?

Tags: sql, join, ssms

I have the following table:

```
ID | Light | TIME
1    Red     8:30
1    Red     9:05
1    Green   9:30
2    Red     7:21
2    Green   7:24
3..
```

I want to get the time of green **after** a red light happened.
For example:

```
ID | Time
1    9:30
2    7:24
...
```

I tried creating joining table tb1 and tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id+1 to find the green light's time but I am having a hard time figuring the time of green that happened after a red light.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(light) over (partition by id order by time) as prev_light
      from t
     ) t
where light <> 'Green' or prev_list <> 'Red';
```